# Lambda function executes three times (expected once)

Tags: aws-event-bridge

My lambda function runs 3 times a day for last several weeks.
As per my (eventbridge) setting, only the first line below is expected.

```
2023/08/09/[$LATEST]712b3f6363e449eb8af65e0582f9518a    2023-08-09 16:45:13 (UTC+05:30)
2023/08/09/[$LATEST]2655f3b267264450b5b7dbce404eb6c2    2023-08-09 11:29:45 (UTC+05:30)
2023/08/09/[$LATEST]16f26cff2187498f97f5dd538dca63b9    2023-08-09 11:15:14 (UTC+05:30)
```

The last 2 lines are not expected in the cloudwatch logs.
I do not know how the function is being called at 11:15 and 11:29

Any help in troubleshooting will be appreciated.

---

Update:

I can see 2 entries in "Scheduler" section. The cron is same as "Rules" (in "Buses" section). But the expected times are shown like this...

```
# in Rules (correct)
Sat, 26 Aug 2023 11:15:00 UTC

# In Schedules (incorrect)
Sun, 27 Aug 2023 11:15:00 (UTC+05:30)
```

I can disable / delete an entry in schedules, but I am not sure why the cron times different for the same entry?

Another question: Is there any way to know more about "11:29" entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the schedules fails because there are 2 schedules set at the same time. The failed one tries again after 15 minutes. May be because of this setting...

```
Flexible time window
15 minutes
```

The scheduler uses different timezone. In my case...

```
Execution timezone
Asia/Calcutta
```

The "Rules" use **UTC timezone** and that is the reason cron runs 3 times a day.

If I disable both schedules, then only "Rules" in "Buses" section will (and should) run. Problem solved.

Comment: I can see the announcement here... https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/

Comment: Instead of creating overlapping services, it is better to integrate rules in schedules.